# How can I run an npm command in a docker container?

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, npm, docker-compose

I am trying to run an angular application in development mode inside a docker container, but when i run it with docker-compose build it works correctly but when i try to put up the container i obtain the below error:

```
ERROR: for sypgod  Cannot start service sypgod: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"npm\": executable file not found in $PATH
```

The real problem is that it doesn't recognize the command npm serve, but why??

The setup would be below:

Docker container (Nginx Reverse proxy -> Angular running in port 4000)

I know that there are better ways of deploying this but at this moment I need this setup for some personals reasons

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10.9 


COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm ci && mkdir /angular && mv ./node_modules ./angular

WORKDIR /angular

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli 

COPY . . 


FROM nginx:alpine
COPY toborFront.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
CMD ["npm", "serve", "--port 4000"]
```

NginxServerSite

```
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name sypgod;


    location / {
            proxy_read_timeout 5m;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/;


    }

}
```

Docker Compose file(the important part where I have the problem)

```
 sypgod: # The name of the service
        container_name: sypgod  # Container name
        build: 
            context: ../angular
            dockerfile: Dockerfile # Location of our Dockerfile
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The image that's finally getting run is this:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY toborFront.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm", "serve", "--port 4000"]
```

The first stage doesn't have any effect (you could `COPY --from=...` files out of it), and if there are multiple `CMD`s, only the last one has an effect.  Since you're running this in a plain `nginx` image, there's no `npm` command, leading to the error you see.

I'd recommend using Node on the host for a live development environment.  When you've built and tested your application and are looking to deploy it, then use Docker if that's appropriate.  In your Dockerfile, run `ng build` in the first stage to compile the application to static files, add a `COPY --from=...` in the second stage to get the built application into the Nginx image, and delete all the `CMD` lines (`nginx` has an appropriate default `CMD`).  @VikramJakhar's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60074429/10008173) has a more complete Dockerfile showing this.

It looks like you might be trying to run both Nginx and the Angular development server in Docker.  If that's your goal, you need to run these in two separate containers.  To do this:

- Split this Dockerfile into two.  Put the `CMD ["npm", "serve"]` line at the end of the first (Angular-only) Dockerfile.
- Add a second block in the `docker-compose.yml` file to run the second container.  The backend `npm serve` container doesn't need to publish `ports:`.
- Change the host name of the backend server in the Nginx config from `localhost` to the Docker Compose name of the other container.

Comment: i have split in two differents dockerFIles, one with the nginx and another with the angular project.
I have quit the ports published, but in the nginx config i am not sure what would be my compose name of the container, would be: sypgod ?
So, the file would be like this:

Comment: What’s the name of the block under `services:` where you declare the second container?  That’s a valid host name.

Comment: is sypgod, but i should add also the port?

Comment: Yes, you need the port (the port inside the container the service is listening on; needs to listen on 0.0.0.0 “all interfaces”; `ports:` have no effect).

Comment: it doesnt, work correctly, i have put this in the nginx conf http://sypgod:4000/ but it doesnt work, the sypgod is the name of the container

Comment: it worked, and now i understand how everything works. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

It would appear the npm can't be accessed from the container.
Try defining where it tries to execute it from:

```
docker run -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app node:10.9 npm serve --port 4000
```

source: https://gist.github.com/ArtemGordinsky/b79ea473e8bc6f67943b

Also make sure that npm is installed on the computer running the docker container.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Why do you need to have npm on the host? It is working without it and wasn't it the whole idea to run npm from docker?

Comment: Follwoing command worked for me: `docker run -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app node:16 sh -c 'npm install --only=prod && npm run build-prod'`

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like below

```
### STAGE 1: Build ###

# We label our stage as ‘builder’
FROM node:alpine as builder

RUN apk --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies add \
    git \
    python \
    make \
    g++

    RUN mkdir -p /ng-app/dist

    WORKDIR /ng-app

    COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

    ## Storing node modules on a separate layer will prevent unnecessary npm installs at each build
    RUN npm install

    COPY . .

    ## Build the angular app in production mode and store the artifacts in dist folder

    RUN npm run ng build -- --prod --output-path=dist


    ### STAGE 2: Setup ###

    FROM nginx:1.14.1-alpine

    ## Copy our default nginx config
    COPY toborFront.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

    ## Remove default nginx website
    RUN rm -rf "/usr/share/nginx/html/*"

    ## From ‘builder’ stage copy over the artifacts in dist folder to default nginx public folder
    COPY --from=builder /ng-app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

    CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: this works because i tried it before, but the problem is that i would like to deploy later in angular server-side rendering, so for that, I must to execute also the npm serve:ssr and then put in a reverse proxy inside Nginx.

how I had to do it, i tried the example that i put in the OP because it was easy and later try the server-side rendering, so your answer is 100% good but not what I need

Answer (score 0):

If you have **Portainer.io** installed for managing your Docker setup, you can open the console for a particular container from a browser.

This is useful if you want to run a reference command like "**npm list**" to show what versions of dependencies have been loaded.

[image: portainer]

So that you can view it like this:

[image: console]

I found this useful for diagnosing issues where an update to a dependency had broken something, which worked fine in a test environment, but the docker version had installed newer minor versions which broke the application.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck at this step:

```bash
docker run -it --rm node /usr/local/bin/npm install
```

Which would instantiate a container from the node image with the default latest tag. run `npm install` inside the container in the predefined working directory. The solution is to simply use a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) in conjunction with setting the working directory:

```bash
docker run -it --rm -v .:/tmp -w /tmp node /usr/local/bin/npm install
```

`.` is the project to run `npm install` in and `/tmp` is just a directory to mount your project in inside the container. Using `/tmp` makes sense since the container will be removed after the command executes due to the `--rm` flag.

P.S. Consider use `node:alpine` or `node:hydrogen-alpine` (`hydrogen` is the codename for lts version 18, but you can use a newer lts version codename) and alias the image locally by tagging it `docker tag ecbe47697d08 node` or `docker tag ecbe47697d08 node:alp`. The alpine image takes up approximately 10 times less disk space, but provides you access to the same version of `npm` as the non alpine image.